# Namespace 'Ember' has no exported member 'RSVP'

Tags: typescript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using typescript with Ember and everything was working fine when suddenly I started getting this error.
Below is the tsconfig.json - (nothing has changed since I last know it was working and checked in)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "****/config/*": ["config/*"],
      "****/tests/*": ["tests/*"],
      "****/*": ["app/*"],
      "****/common/*": ["common/*"],
      "npm:*": ["local-types/*"],
      "*": ["local-types/*"],
      "tslib": ["node_modules/tslib/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "bower_components"
    ],
    "watch": false
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "mirage/**/*.ts",
    "common/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsc --version
Version 2.2.1

Has anyone else faced this before? I am clueless for many hours now.

Comment: Why do you believe the issue is with your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I am not sure at this point what is the issue. May be something changed with Ember.

Comment: If you've updated any dependencies look at the change logs and see if any api's became deprecated / changed. With just what you've given us here it would be almost impossible to be able to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an Ember update issue and not TypeScript. Decided not to upgrade and have breaking changes at this point fixed the issue.
ps - removed all the ^ from package.json to stop it from automatically upgrading the packages.

Comment: you might want to give https://yarnpkg.com/ a try which will automatically "lock" all your dependencies